# "Ihres" or "Ihre" in the phrase "Richtigkeit ihres Handelns"

Tags: adjective, inflection

> "So konnte sie doch die ganze Welt von der Richtigkeit ihres Handelns überzeugen."

**ihres Handelns**: I think it is strong inflection plural, so should sound "ihre Handelns"

If it is the correct phrase, then what the rule applies here?

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ihr#Possessivpronomen

Answer (score 7):

Whose correctness?
The correctness of her actions.

"Ihres Handelns" is genitive (interrogative: whose?).

So the correct sentence is:

> "So konnte sie doch die ganze Welt von der Richtigkeit **ihres** Handelns überzeugen."

> "So she was able to convince the whole world of the correctness of her actions."

"Note that although *Handeln* can be translated as *actions*, it is **not plural**, because an infinitive can (usually) not be plural. A more literal translation would be *action* or *doing*." - RHa

Comment: Note that although *Handeln* can be translated as *actions*, it is not plural, because an infinitive can (usually) not be plural. A more literal translation would be *action* or *doing*.

Comment: @RHa nice addition!

Comment: Please don't put comments in your answer.

Comment: @Olafant why not?

Comment: @choXer Because German SE is a QA forum. If you want to ask OP a question, write a comment. If you want to answer the question, write an answer.

Comment: @Olafant okay, i understand what you mean. but since it is not just a comment, but the "comment" part of my answer, i  think it's legitimate.

Comment: @choXer I don't understand. *Did you use a dictionary?* doesn't add anything useful to your answer.

Comment: @Olafant  That is not what I meant. 
I think it doesn't matter if there is a comment at the beginning of my question or not. I don't understand why you see it so narrowly.
If i had only written a comment as my answer, i would understand you.

Comment: @choXer The answer is not only for OP but for anyone who might have the same or a similar question. So an answer is just not the right place for a comment. Don't answer in comments, don't comment in answers.

Comment: @choXer Thanks for removing the discussed initial sentence, especially as it doesn’t contribute content and may even be flagged as “unfriendly or unkind” - No joke, the [CoC](https://german.stackexchange.com/conduct) is pretty clear here. And how should the asker reply? Not all users have the privilege to comment everywhere, but all can comment on their own posts. And finally, unlike answers, comments are non-permanent by design, so can be removed whenever they’ve become obsolete - and removing them creates work for the mods.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct.

The part *"ihres Handelns"* is a genitive attribute of *"Richtigkeit".*

Translation:

> So konnte sie doch die ganze Welt von der *Richtigkeit **ihres Handelns*** überzeugen.
> So she was able to convince the whole world of ***her actions** correctness.*